# Master/detail editing - passing value to detail model property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two tables `Deal` and `DealDetail`. I create two controller methods.

```
    //
    // GET: /DealDetail/Create/5

    public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        var deal = _db.Deals.Find(id);
        ViewBag.Deal = deal;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /DealDetail/Create/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(int id, DealDetail dealdetail)
    {
        dealdetail.DealId = id;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.DealDetails.Add(dealdetail);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(dealdetail);
    }
```

However, how to make sure the following html code to post using url of `/DealDetail/Create/5` instead of `/DealDetail/Create`?

```
@Html.Partial("_Deal", (Models.Deal)ViewBag.Deal)
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        ......
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Or is there a way to set the `DealDetail.DealID` to the value of `ViewBag.Deal.DealId`(id) in the cshtml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this ought to do what you're looking for:

```
Html.BeginForm("Create","DealDetail", new { id = Model.DealID }, FormMethod.Post);
```

Whether you assign id from your Model or ViewBag, the important point is to assign id, the route engine and your existing Controller logic should do the rest.